# Squid3 proxy server is not working for a single website

Tags: proxy, squid, website, permissions

I face an annoying and hard to track its root problem with squid3 proxy server running on Ubuntu Server 12.04.

Squid is working fine for all websites I have tried so far to access, except http://ubuntuforums.org/

What I get is the following error:

> ERROR
>
> The requested URL could not be retrieved
>
> The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL:
>   http:// ubuntuforums.org/
>
> Access Denied.
>
> Access control configuration prevents your request from being allowed
>   at this time. Please contact your service provider if you feel this is
>   incorrect.
>
> Your cache administrator is **webmaster**.

Notice also that the cache administrator is **webmaster**, while I have changed the *cache_mgr* parameter in the squid.conf file with my own e-mail and for any other errors I see it properly.

In the access.log I see this every time I try to access this web page.

> 1355572568.095    217 192.168.0.10 TCP_MISS/403 4567 GET http:// ubuntuforums.org/ - DIRECT/91.189.94.12 text/html

The bizarre thing here is that I can access sub paths of the same domain like http://ubuntuforums.org/index.php without any problems!

I tried to purge the cache for this website using **squidclient** but again I get the following error:

```
# squidclient -m PURGE http://ubuntuforums.org/
HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found
Server: squid/3.1.19
Mime-Version: 1.0
Date: Sat, 15 Dec 2012 12:14:48 GMT
Content-Length: 0
X-Cache: MISS from localhost
X-Cache-Lookup: NONE from localhost:3128
Via: 1.0 localhost (squid/3.1.19)
Connection: close
```

Answer (score 1):

If your data is correct, then there ist nothing wrong with squid.

The url you posted is  `http:// ubuntuforums.org/` - see the space between `http://` and `ubuntufoums.org/`

Comment: It's been a long time since I had this problem. After a few days, the problem was "automagically" fixed. So indeed, it could be some mistyping, however, I am pretty sure I had tried to retype the link again and again. Thanks for point this out though!